# Caffe calculate issue

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a question. I have a dataset that contains 5-10 photos (only for test run).
Using the example of a model bvlc_reference_caffenet I ran caffe. 
But caffe process works about ~ 1 day. Please tell me if this is normal?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: no. this is not normal. caffe should take <1sec / image even using CPU (far less for GPU), depending on models and architecture. But I never came across models that run for hours on a single image, let alone a day.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I found the problem - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/caffe-users/hang%7Csort:relevance/caffe-users/rDxoUMjqsJA/3a7hWNWCDQAJ but this solution does not help me. p.s Sorry for my English